# VBA created with Excel 2003 loaded OK in Excel 2007, but there's nothing in Project tree of VB editor

Tags: excel, vba, xla

I have created a VBA in excel 2003 and save it in xla format. This AddIn add a new menu and some submenu in toolbar of Excel. All work well until I upgrade to Office 2007, then I open the xla file. No error message shown, but when I view the macro List, no items there. I open the Visual Basic editor. My old Project (named ML) is still there, but nothing in the Project tree, just default files as when add a new blank project.
I open the xla file with notepad, and my variable, function name are still there. Anyone has experience in this weird behavior, please give me a clue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean you can't open an xla with Office 2007?

Comment: In fact nothing happen when I double click the xla file. When I open VB editor, there's a project named 'ML' (that's the name I set before). But all my modules created disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar add-ins generally appear in the add-ins tab of the ribbon in Excel 2007. Make sure you have the add-ins tab displayed (if not you can turn it on under excel options).

If that still isn't working you'll need to go online and read up on altering the code to conform to the ribbon - there are a lot of resources out there should you need to do this.

Comment: The problem is not that it can't add function to Excel (ribbon or something like that) but the whole project source (that's mean all modules) went away, although project name still shown in VB editor.

Comment: Oh, my. :( not sure off the top of my head but I'll look around as well!